# Periodic javascript requests stop happening

Tags: javascript, browser-cache

I am using RightJS which is very similar to jQuery on a webapp. I have setup a periodic event that is supposed to send a request to the server and update an element on the page with the result every second. The code looks like this.

```
var update_temp = function (){
    $('current_temp').load("/api/temp");
}
update_temp.periodical(1000);
```

This code seems to work fine for a while but randomly it will stop working and the element stops being updated. I put a breakpoint in the javascript code in the browser at the line `$('current_temp').load("/api/temp");` and the breakpoint does continue to get hit every second. However, for some reason the browser doesn't seem to be issuing the request to the server. In the Chrome developer tools there is a 'Network' tab that lets you see requests that are being made. I see no more requests happening.

Could this be a cacheing problem? Or could it be that one of the requests never returned so the browser stops issuing requests to that url?

If I type the .../api/temp directly into the browser address bar and hit refresh it returns the temperature just fine every time.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try the caching problem. Try to add a timestamp after each request .. i. e. something like this:

```
var update_temp = function (){
    $('current_temp').load("/api/temp?killcache=" + (new Date()).getTime());
}
update_temp.periodical(1000);
```

Comment: This seems to have fixed it. I'll report back with more info if I find the problem comes back. Thanks.